# Unable to detect user current location on android device

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am developing small android application in which I want to find user current location.
My code structure for detecting user location looks like .

```
private void sendSMS(Context context, Intent intent)
{ 
     final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
     final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

     LocationManager locationManager;
     locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
         LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
     MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
     MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
    new MyLocationListener()
     );

     Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     String loc_message = null;

     if (location != null) 
     {
     loc_message =String.format(
         "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
         location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
      );
    Toast.makeText(context, loc_message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}   
 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         String message = String.format(
                 "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                 location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
         );
     }

     public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {

     }

     public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
     }

     public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
     }
     }
}
```

Working fine on simulator where I send coordinates from DDMS. But when I run it on device it not giving me output.On my device I keep Use GPS satellites enable. But when I tried to find user location it's not giving any output.... Need Help... Thank you.......

Comment: Note, that getting a GPS coordinate can take up to several minutes depending on your location, it is also possible, that you won't get a location fix at all, if your phone can't see enough satellites. It could be because of you are indoors, or because of poor weather. I advise you to be patient, also it would be a better practice, to register your LocationListener inside your activity's `onCreate(...)` method, and unregister it in `onDestroy(...)`. Keep checking your logs in the LogCat, you will be able to find out whether you got a fix or not.

Comment: which real devices you are using i,e which company of it .......... because some chinese tab does not support gps while you have to use network or wifi provider for that............

Comment: Thank you for reply.I am using samsunge (android 2.1).

Comment: Instead of GPS_PROVIDER If I use NETWORK_PROVIDER it gives me proper output(coordinates of location). But if I use gps as location provider it not giving me any output. I wait for sufficient amount of time for... @paradx any solution... need help...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the skeleton of the GPS `Service` I used in my tracking application, it has been tested, and works fine I can guarantee that. I hope it will help you out.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class TrackingService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final long TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000L;
    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE = 0L;

    private WakeLock mWakeLock;

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    private final Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private LocationListener mLocationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Your code here
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    private void registerLocationListener() {
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TrackingService: Do not have any location manager.");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to register location listener w/ TrackingService...");
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE, mLocationListenerGps);
            Log.d(TAG, "...location listener now registered w/ TrackingService @ " + TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not register location listener: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void unregisterLocationListener() {
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TrackingService: Do not have any location manager.");
            return;
        }
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListenerGps);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location listener now unregistered w/ TrackingService.");
    }

    private TimerTask mCheckLocationListenerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Re-registering location listener with TrackingService.");
                    unregisterLocationListener();
                    registerLocationListener();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        registerLocationListener();

        mTimer.schedule(mCheckLocationListenerTask, 1000 * 60 * 5, 1000 * 60);

        acquireWakeLock();

        Log.d(TAG, "Service started...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handleStartCommand(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handleStartCommand(intent, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void handleStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                getText(R.string.trackingservice_notification_rolling_text),
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
                getText(R.string.trackingservice_notification_ticker_title),
                getText(R.string.trackingservice_notification_ticker_text),
                contentIntent);

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true);
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer.purge();
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        unregisterLocationListener();
        releaseWakeLock();
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service stopped...");
    }

    private void acquireWakeLock() {
        try {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            if (pm == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "TrackRecordingService: Power manager not found!");
                return;
            }
            if (mWakeLock == null) {
                mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
                if (mWakeLock == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "TrackRecordingService: Could not create wake lock (null).");
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                mWakeLock.acquire();
                if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "TrackRecordingService: Could not acquire wake lock.");
                }
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TrackRecordingService: Caught unexpected exception: "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Releases the wake lock if it's currently held.
     */
    private void releaseWakeLock() {
        if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your AndroidManifest.xml file you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Just fill out the GPS location listener, Register the service in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, start the service from your activity, and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for reply.. In my code if I use Network as location provider then it's working fine.But if I use gps as network provider it not giving any output. Any suggestion.. thank for your ans. I will try your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nilkash, I experienced the same problem on my Samsung Galaxy 5.

I got my problem solved because of your suggestion to change as network provider. Thanks for that Buddy . I got the solution.

"Network Provider" determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved by means of a network lookup. Requires either of the permissions android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

But "GPS Provider" determines location using satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return a location fix. Requires the permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

This is the problem with device, our device does not support gps without internet it only uses location provider.